# I'm unable to setup the Spring Social ShowCase project in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-social

The gradle is unable to build and unable to resolve the following:

- maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
- maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }

Comment: Does it build properly from the command line Gradle?

Comment: Nopes it doesn't